# $5$ Integers are paired in all possible ways and each pair of integers is added.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> $5$ Integers are paired in all possible ways and each pair of integers
>   is added. The $10$ sums obtained are $1,4,7,5,8,9,11,14,15,10$. What are the
>   $5$ integers?

This is what I got so far:

To get all possible pairs, each integer must be paired with the other $4$ integers.

At this point I am stuck. Is the only way to try all possible pairs and see what works? There must be an easier way...

EDIT: Fixed TYPO

Comment: you wrote down $9$ sums, not $10$!

Comment: Typo is fixed...

Comment: Maybe not-see my comment to my answer.  I don't think you can do this.  But it shows a way to eliminate many possiblities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding your sums gives $84$.  As each number participates in four pairs, the sum of the integers is $21$.  The top two sum to $15$ and the bottom two to $1$, so the middle one is $5$.  The top two are then $7,8$ or $6,9$, but $7,8$ would produce $12$, which is absent, so the top three are $5,6,9$, which account for $11,14,15$  Then $10$ cannot come from $4+6$ because we are missing $13$, so must be $1+9$.  As the bottom two sum to $1$, the other is $0$ and the solution is $0,1,5,6,9$

Comment: Your "solution" gives 6 in two different ways (and not in the list), but does not give 4 or 8.

Comment: @hardmath:  good point.  It looks like we want to get $1$ from $-1,2$ giving a list of $-1,2,5,6,9$, but that doesn't give $10$  That would give a list of $1,4,5,7,8,11,14,15$ with $8$ and $11$ twice.  I claim there is no solution.  My original gives $1,5,6,7,9,10,11,14,15$ with $6$ twice.

Comment: I'm with you! (on there being no solution)

Comment: Yeah, it seems like the problem itself is bad. I think it was supposed the list you gave (1,4,5,7,8,11,14,15 with 8 and 11 twice) as the book lists −1,2,5,6,9 as the answer but gives the wrong list of sums.

Answer (score 1):

1well you have in one sense an overdetermined problem, since there are ten equations in five unknowns.

however, you are unsure which equation gives which result.
a sensible procedure would be to begin by ordering the unknowns:
$$
x_1 \le x_2 \le x_3 \le x_4 \le x_5
$$

however you know also that (by adding all equations) 
$$
4\sum_{i=1}^5 x_i = 74
$$
but since $4 \not \mid 74$ there may be a difficulty...

added: just seen Tim's comment! i didn't do the due diligence of counting!!!

now the typo is fixed, we get $84$ for the sum, so that the five numbers must add to 21.
one definite step we can take is to assume that the smallest and largest sums must be the sums of the two smallest and the two largest numbers, so that
$$
x_1+x_2= 1 \\
x_4+x_5=15
$$
adding these and subtracting from $21$ gives us the definite result that $x_3=5$. the fact that the second smallest sum must be $x_1+x_3$ allows you to ascertain $x_1$, and so forth.

Comment: OP only gave $9$ of the $10$ sums, which is probably why there is that inconsistency

Comment: yes, a typo! well spotted

Comment: I fixed the typo...